# Jstree Leaf Node is icon is coming as expandable. I want minus(-) sign for leaf nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jstree, jstree-search

I have set theme as

```
  "themes": {
                     "theme": "proton"
                 },
```

My js tree Image with leaf [image]node sign as (+) which is non expandable.see highlighted

Comment: make a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 13):

It would be beneficial for anyone else who wants to change the triangles in the new theme from jsTree 3.0 back to the plus/minus sign from the previous version for any reason.

Here's how I do it:

1. I copied the 32px.png from the jsTree 3.0 default theme under themes/default folder.
   [image: 32px.png from jsTree 3.0]
2. I also need the plus/minus sign from the previous version of jsTree so I copied it as well. 
   [image: background image from previous version of jsTree]
3. Then I used the gimp2 software to copy the plus and minus signs over.
   **Note: the icons from new version 32px.png are 32x32 pixel while the icons from the old version are 18x18 pixel.**
4. I don't know what platform/framework you're using to develop the software but I am using Asp.Net MVC. It's better not to create the new theme "plusminus" in same themes folder along with the plugin because the next time when you update the plugin the new theme you created will get overridden. I just created another folder under Content and copied all the files from themes/default/folder over (and you only need to replace the 32px.png with the custom one you just created).
5. Here is my custom 32px.png with plug and minus sign instead of the triangle.

   [image: custom background image with plus minus sign]

Comment: Wrong reply. I think he's asking how to tell jstree that the nodes are leaf nodes. And he propably doesn't really want the minus symbol either.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `status: "closed"` to your nodes.

E.g. `{"id":5,"title":"node", status: "closed" }`

Answer (score 0):

To inform jstree that the nodes are leaf nodes, for version 1.0 the `state` should be set to `"leaf"`and for 3.0 the `children` property should be set to `false`.